# How to pass an Argument to Method in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, object, methods, parameter-passing

I'm trying to use this Perl Method: HTML::Highlight - A module to highlight words or patterns in HTML documents.

The methode itself isn't acctualy the problem but the way how I can pass a Attribute.

Example which works:

```
use HTML::Highlight;
$text = 'Lorem ipsum Velit ullamco ex anim quis Duis laboris ut proident velit eu dolor Ut amet proident aliqua minim officia sunt commodo veniam dolor id reprehenderit reprehenderit non nulla incididunt mollit exercitation minim commodo ut quis laboris ex proident.';

# create the highlighter object

my $hl = new HTML::Highlight (
        words => [
            'ex',
            'ul',
    ],
    wildcards => [
            undef,
    ],
    colors => [
            'red; font: bold',
    ],
    debug => 0
);

my $hl_document = $hl->highlight($text);

print $hl_document;
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
use HTML::Highlight;
$text = 'Lorem ipsum Velit ullamco ex anim quis Duis laboris ut proident velit eu dolor Ut amet proident aliqua minim officia sunt commodo veniam dolor id reprehenderit reprehenderit non nulla incididunt mollit exercitation minim commodo ut quis laboris ex proident.';

# create the highlighter object

@keywords = "ex", "ul";

my $hl = new HTML::Highlight (
    words => @keywords,
    wildcards => [
            undef,
    ],
    colors => [
            'red; font: bold',
    ],
    debug => 0
);

my $hl_document = $hl->highlight($text);

print $hl_document;
```

As you can see in the code snippet above, I'd like to pass an existing array to the object.

How can I do that correctly?

Currently I get an exeption like that:
HTML::Highlight - "words" and "wildcards" parameters must be references to arrays at C:\Skripts\Perl\syntax_highlight.pl line 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in error message, pass a reference:

```
my $hl = HTML::Highlight->new(
    words => \@keywords,
#     here __^
    wildcards => [
            undef,
    ],
    colors => [
            'red; font: bold',
    ],
    debug => 0
);
```